# How to check the special charaters in a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I want to find all the rows having special characters in a column value.

Basically I have a description column in a table and need to find the columns having special characters like `($#%&*()@!'";:,)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%'
```

The '^' symbol means NOT one of the following: 0-9 (numbers), a-z (lowercase letters), A-Z (uppercase letters) and a space.

In which case, the only thing left are: special characters.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT Colname
FROM TABLE
WHERE Colname like '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```